# If $\mathbb E[XU]=\mathbb E[YU]$ for all $U$ does $X=Y$ a.s.?

Tags: probability

Let $X,Y$ integrable random variable. I was wondering, does $$\mathbb E[XU]=\mathbb E[YU]$$
for all bounded r.v. $U$, does $X=Y$ a.s. ? In other words, it's a sort of fondamental lemma of calculs of variation but here $U$ is not $\mathcal C^\infty _c$ but only a bounded r.v.

If $X$ and $Y$ are bounded, then we can take $U=X-Y$ and thus get $\mathbb E[(X-Y)^2]=0$ which implies that $X=Y$ a.s.. But what happen in the case $X-Y$ is not bounded ? I think it's true, but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: Take, for each $n$, $U=(X-Y)1(|X-Y| \leq n)$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $U=1_{X>Y}$, then observe that we should have $X\le Y $ a.s. There is everything interchangeable between $X$ and $Y$, so $X=Y$ a.s.

Comment: why do you get $X\leq Y$ a.s. ? with $U=1_{X>Y}$ we get $\mathbb E[X1_{X>Y}]\geq \mathbb E[Y 1_{X>Y}]$, but why this should give $X\leq Y$ a.s. ?

Comment: Just observe that $\mathbb E((X-Y)1_{X>Y})=\mathbb E(X-Y;X>Y)=\mathbb E(|X-Y|;X>Y)=0.$

Comment: Thank you. Actually, $\mathbb E[X-Y\mid X>Y]=\frac{1}{\mathbb P(X>Y)}\mathbb E[(X-Y)1_{X>Y}]$ and not what you wrote, but I see. Thank you.

Comment: Anytime! But observe that semicolon is just a notation for what I used above and it is not conditional expectation.

Answer (score 1):

Using Monotone convergence
$$\mathbb E[(X-Y)^2]=\lim_{n\to \infty }\mathbb E\big[(X-Y)(X-Y)\boldsymbol 1_{\{|X-Y|\leq n\}}\big]=0,$$
since by hypothesis $\mathbb E[(X-Y)U]=0$ for all $U$ bounded.